# Where does cache lie in clean architecture

Tags: caching, repository-pattern, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

For one of my microservices projects, I decided to structure the code as controllers, services, and repositories. The API call routes to the controller, which then calls the service, which then calls the repository. Each of these layers interacts with the next layer via an interface to keep things decoupled.

All was fine until I needed a cache.

Imagine I already have a CustomerRepository interface having `findById(int id)` method, with one implementation that interacts with DB (`DbCustomerRepositoryImpl`). Now I need to cache this information due to some reason. So I create an implementation of CustomerRepository that interacts with the cache (`CacheCustomerRepositoryImpl`), `findById(int id)` does a simple `cache.get()` and returns the response. But where do I handle the cache miss?

1. I could handle the cache miss in the service layer, and interact with the `DbCustomerRepositoryImpl` of CustomerRepository when there is a cache miss, (and potentially write in the cache). But this leads to the coupling of the service and the repository. If down the line, I decide to only use `DbCustomerRepositoryImpl`, then I would have unwanted code that handles cache miss in service, or in the worst case, need some code changes in the service.
2. I could handle the cache miss in the repository layer - the `CacheCustomerRepositoryImpl` will first check in the cache, in the case of a cache miss, interact with the `DbCustomerRepositoryImpl` and return the result to the service. This looks fine because according to me, the repository layer should just get the data, no matter from where, it doesn't matter to the service layer. But this has a pitfall. If I need to cache the business logic's response, what should I do? Would the service layer call `CacheCustomerRepositoryImpl` and then this call the service layer? This kind of adds circular dependency in the application which I am trying to avoid.

I could think of these 2 cases, each case might have its own pros and cons. But I need some help to figure out which might be the better case, or if there is a better approach to caching in clean architecture.

Comment: If repository has enough information to handle cache miss, then imo the repository should implement caching internally. If not then not. You can mix both styles if both cases happen, why not. Caching does not have to be done in single way, it can have layers.

Comment: "*the `CacheCustomerRepositoryImpl` will first check in the cache, in the case of a cache miss, interact with the `DbCustomerRepositoryImpl`*" - actually, it should interact only with any generic `CustomerRepository` (i.e. use the interface), unless the service/business layer *needs* additional info about the implementation (like `isCached`). But yes, this is the way to go - a cache is a prime example for the decorator pattern.

Comment: @Bergi you are right, the `CacheCustomerRepositoryImpl` interacts with `CustomerRepository` interface instead of directly interacting with the `DbCustomerRepositoryImpl`.

Comment: "*If I need to cache the business logic's response, what should I do?*" - well that's a different cache, not the customer repository cache. This caching should happen where "*the API call routes to the controller*", i.e. on the input adapter

Comment: @Bergi you mean the controller will call the cached implementation of the service?(service layer has business logic)

Comment: @potatoxchip Yes, if you need to implement the caching yourself. Or the controller returns a cachable response to wherever it was called from, e.g. the http request handler, which could do http caching on its own

Comment: What if one method of the service `A()`, calls another method of the same service `B()`. And I want to have a cache on `B()` - such that no matter who calls `B()`, it will first get from cache, in case of cache miss, compute the result and return? But I also want the implementation of service to be de-coupled from the repository

Comment: Depending on the language and its implementation of dynamic dispatch, wrapping the service in a cachedService might not be enough to intercept internal calls to `B()`, you might need to use subclassing instead to override `B` with a cached version. Or split out `B` into a separate service. But probably the easier choice here is to have the service know about the cache, i.e. using a `BresultRepository` that is implemented either with a cache or by default with something that ignores stores and always returns "not cached", so that the service would "re"compute its `B` results on every call.

Answer (score 3):

For most applications caching is a technical detail which, in Clean Architecture, should be in the interface adapters layer.

In order to cache data coming from a repository i would apply the decorator pattern. Your CachingRepository implements same interface as the actual repository, takes the cache implementation and the real repository as constructor dependency and then always first checks the cache on read and falls back on the real repository in case of cache miss. It updates the cache on write API calls.
See also: https://youtu.be/e_-bf93vx10?si=LxN8jbHKmhu5PgRe

If you additionally need caching of the business logic response, I would add separate caching on controller level. In Asp.Net this can easily be done with a custom middleware.